# Change field label/string

Tags: invoice, odoo-14

I'm trying to change field label/string on amount_by_group field that is showing total tax amount on Invoice form.

Tried to do it like this - using field attributes

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='amount_by_group']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="string">Porez</attribute>
</xpath>
```

No luck, also tried to replace field with the same field but with string defined

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='amount_by_group']" position="replace">
    <field name="amount_by_group" widget="tax-group-custom-field" nolabel="1" colspan="2" attrs="{'invisible': [('amount_tax', '=', 0)]}" string="Tax"/>
</xpath>
```

I used methods described here (first two points in answer by Cybrosys) https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/change-field-label-through-python-149963

Does anybody have clue how to change that fields name? At the moment field label is "Neoporezivo" and I'd like to show it as "Porez".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried is correct. It seems in your case, you have to update field translation.

When we load a new language, Odoo translates terms based on *.po* file given the folder *i18n* in the related module.

You can try first from the front end and if it works, you can override *.po* file.

Try this:

- Active developer mode.
- Go to Settings > Translations > Translated Terms
- Find your displayed term and edit it with your desired term.
- Refresh your page and check your form. It should update with the desired term.

**EDIT**:

[image]

Comment: Bhavesh, thank you for your answer. I tried to find translation but no luck, there are some strings named like that but aren't changing anything. I appreciate your help, It is defined somewhere else (can't find it in code) - I will mark your answer as correct but in my case there is something else happening.

Comment: Make sure you have necessary access rights of the setting. Also turn on developer mode (I know you already did that). I edit my answer with screen reference - Odoo 13 CE and menu location is same in EE.